# Gremlin groupCount() return only gt 2

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I have the following Gremlin traversal, running on Azure CosmosDB, and I only want to return URLs with a count greater than 1.  I'm not sure how to limit the return from the groupCount().

`g.V().hasLabel('article').values('url').groupCount()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example from the modern toy graph:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('software').in().
......1>   groupCount().
......2>     by('name').
......3>   unfold().
......4>   filter(select(values).unfold().is(gt(1)))
==>josh=2
```

So you do the `groupCount()` and then `unfold()` the resulting `Map` then `filter()` the individual `values` from the `Map`.

In your case you would probably have something like:

```
g.V().hasLabel('article').
  groupCount()
    by('url').
  unfold().
  filter(select(values).unfold().is(gt(1)))
```

Comment: It doesn't look like Azure CosmosDB Graph supports the **filter** step, so I used the **where** step as follows to get the results I was looking for.  Thank you for the assist.

`g.V().hasLabel('article').groupCount().by('url').unfold().where(select(values).is(gt(1)))`

Answer (score 4):

Per my comment on the answer from Stephen Mallette, Azure CosmosDB Graph https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin-support doesn't support the **filter** step so I used the **where** step to achieve the desired results.

`g.V().hasLabel('article').groupCount().by('url').unfold().where(select(values).is(gt(1)))`